# redirect everything to https://www for main domain except for for subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

I want these redirects

```
http://example.com => https://www.example.com
http://www.example.com => https://www.example.com
https://example.com => https://www.example.com
https://example.com/asa.php => https://www.example.com/asa.php
http://subdomain.example.com => https://subdomain.example.com
https://www.subdomain.example.com => https://subdomain.example.com
```

What I have tried is

```
#redirect http or https to https//www.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But these rules handle all domains of the site, not just the main site.

The idea is to make all the incoming **http** to **https**.
And all **main site** **non-www** to **www**.
And for **subdomain** from **www** to **non-www** if any.

Answer (score 2):

All in all, these are three separate requests.

1. change http to https, this should already work as is

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
   ```
2. redirect main site example.com to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). This can be done by being more specific

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
   RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
   ```
3. redirect non main sites from [www.subdomain.example.com](http://www.subdomain.example.com) to subdomain.example.com. To strip the leading www, you can capture the part after www., and use the captured subdomain in the rewrite rule

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+\.example\.com)$
   RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
   ```

Finally, put 1. at the end to avoid two redirects for e.g. http://example.com or http://www.subdomain.example.com

---

Unrelated, but *never* test with [`R=301`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/1741542)!